# Using ajax to create a html table based on database array elements in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a website where you can select a row of a table and that would display another table without refreshing the page. The new table is based on a string that is converted to an array and separated based on commas.

The table is generated on the server side, not within html with php elements. I cannot seem to get the table to show all the elements of the original string, now as an array, and add them dynamically as rows.

Here is the server side code:

```
if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
    $id = $_GET['query'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE sample_id=$id;";


    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $input1 = $input['micro_analysis'];

    $rows = var_dump(explode(',', $input1));

    if (count($rows) > 0) {
        $output .= 
        '<thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Tests</th>                      
        </tr>                                   
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        foreach ($rows as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row);
            '<tr>
            <td>'; echo implode('</td><td>', $row); 
            '</td>                
            </tr>';
        endforeach;  
        '</tbody>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

In the case for better understanding the variable `$input1` will look something like this:

```
$input1 = "1,2,44,67";
```

When using `var_dump(explode(',', $input1));` it produces an array like this:

`array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(2) "44" [3]=> string(2) "67" }`

So now I need the table to create under the column tests a row with "1", then a new row with "2" and so on...

Can anybody please help?

Comment: In your foreach, you don't echo the html, just have it in limbo without echo, you only echo the implode of the $row

Comment: I  keep getting this error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in....

Comment: Because you're assigning a var_dump to $rows, var_dump dosn't produce a usable variable, only output, foreach expects an array, $rows is null / empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$input1` is a simple string separated by commas then something like this should be enough:

```
$input1 = "1,2,44,67";

$rows = explode(',', $input1);
$output = "";
if (count($rows) > 0) {
    $output .= '<thead><tr><th>Tests</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $output .= '<tr><td>' . $row . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</tbody>';
}
echo $output;
```

No need to use `array_map` and `explode` again, just loop through each result inside `$rows` and use string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you this was much simpler that I imagined!

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `var_dump` from `$rows = var_dump(explode(',', $input1));`. Also need to append every html string to `$output` and echo it at the end.

Code should be like:

```
$rows = explode(',', $input1);
$output = "";
if (count($rows) > 0) {
    $output .= '<thead><tr><th>Tests</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    foreach ($rows as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row);
        $output .= '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $row) . '</td></tr>';
    endforeach;
    $output .= '</tbody>';
}
echo $output;
```